# Complex polynomial problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n\geq1$ and let $z\in \mathbb{C}$
. Show that there is a polynomial $h(z)$ of degree $n-1$ such that $p(z)=(z-z_0)h(z)+p(z_0) $. Inparticular, if $p(z_0) = 0$, then $p(z) = (z-z_0)h(z)$.

Just begun learning complex analysis by my own. Should i use the polynomial remainder theorem somehow, does it work for complex functions? Or should i use a more elementary approach with the defintion on a complex polynomial?

Comment: It is a special case of the Remainder Theorem.

Comment: One can always Divide (with Remainder) by any polynomial that is *monic* (lead coeff $= 1).\,$ From this Division Algorithm follows immediately the Factor and Remainder Theorem.